# Can't connect routes in Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have the following structure

```
project

-app/

--controllers/

---home.js

--models/

---home.js

--views/

---home.html

-db/

--db.js

-index.js
```

my controller home.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var database = require('../models/home');
var path = require('path');

router.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'home.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now I want to make that route useful, so in my `index.js` I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(require('./app/controllers/home')); //<-- this is what I ask for

app.listen(3000, function(err ) {
    //......
})
```

But now I have more then just route to 'home', so instead of

```
 app.use(require('./app/controllers/home'));
 app.use(require('./app/controllers/about'));
 app.use(require('./app/controllers/etc'));
```

I read that I can use:

```
app.use(require('./app/controllers/'));
```

But I get error that the module cannot be found. Can you suggest me how can I easily get all my routes in use? Thanks :)

Comment: add `app/controllers/index.html` which exports all of your routers. This will allow you to `require('./app/controllers')`

Comment: `app.use(require('./app/controllers/home'));` this line does not seem to be correct . are you sure you are following right?

Comment: @wilusdaman I believe you meant `index.js`. Yes, that solved my problem. But still, I can't understand why both 'require('./app/controllers')' and 'require('./app/controllers/index')' work. I think that the first one shouldn't work.. Can you explain me this?

Comment: Ah, yes, I did mean `index.js`. `require('./app/controllers/index')` works just like requiring any other file/ module works. `require('./app/controllers')` also works because it's a [feature of Node's module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) (common JS).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right you're trying to route a router to a different relative path.
You can set a relative path by passing that path as the first parameter. Then any route inside of your router that uses app.get/use/... will start from that relative path.

Inside index.js

```
app.use("/home", require('./app/controllers/home'));
app.use("/about", require('./app/controllers/about'));
app.use("/etc", require('./app/controllers/etc'));
```

inside ./app/controllers/home and other routes

```
router.get("/", ...) // this will be located at localhost/home
router.get("/myhouse, ...) // this will be located at localhost/home/myhouse
```

Also worth metioning you can route a router inside a router

```
router.use("/", require('path/to/another-router.js'))
```

Comment: shouldn't this `app.get("/", ...)` be `router.get("/", ...)` ?